# Fragment lifecycle and IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-fragments

My application has an activity called HomeActivity which contains a fragment which contains a webview.

When the webview is loading there is a progressdialog that open and close.

My application use Parse.com to receive some push, when a push is received it opens the HomeActivity. When the application it not open all is ok but when the application is already in background it crashs (not always) with the error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeActivityFragment{11e3f482} not attached to Activity
        at android.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:788)
        at com.myieseg.fragment.HomeActivityFragment$1.onPageStarted(HomeActivityFragment.java:64)
```

It crashes on the line :

```
 dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null,getResources().getString(R.string.plzwait));
```

I think, I will add a catch IllegalStateException because in this case I dont care about the dialog, but I would like to understand how I could handle this error properly.

thanks

Here is the fragment code :

```
public class HomeActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView webView = null;

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    public HomeActivityFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        int url = R.string.defaulturl;
        if (bundle != null) {
            url = bundle.getInt("index", R.string.defaulturl);            
        }

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);



         webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        if(webView!=null){
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {                
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null,getResources().getString(R.string.plzwait));
                       dialog.setCancelable(true);                    
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    dialog.dismiss();                    
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.errorwebview), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl(getResources().getString(url) );

        }

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if(dialog!=null){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start the dialog only if your fragment is not paused. Set a flag to true in `onPause()` and set it to false in `onResume()`.

Comment: Where is ` dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null,getResources().getString(R.string.plzwait));
` called from?